# Google Analytics tracking on external search widget

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have a search box for the content of my website that I will be putting on my clients own sites.

The search box allows them to find access guides on my site.

The search box consists of a snippet of HTML, Js and CSS

When i put this search box onto a client site i want to be able to track when/how many times the search button is clicked and also if possible the search keywords that are used.

How would i do this using google analytics?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: For this there are google analytics tool. You may read their docs and work out as per your requirement. I m sure you will get it definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create a new property in Analytics with its own tracking code. Then in the JS snippet that you add to your clients sites, add in your Analytics Tracking Code. This will allow you to see anything on their sites just as would be on your own. The next step would be to add in analytics event tracking. You could capture the search term and send that to analytics in the event.

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
<script>
//using jQuery
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
    var searchval = $('#search').val();
    ga('send', 'event', 'search', 'used', searchval);
});
</script>
```

This will add in the value of their search into the analytics event. You can then look at the events to see how many searches / how often / the various terms used.

Comment: Thank you so much much! However, we have a 120,00 guides and over 300+ clients, would this approach mean i need to have 300 extra lines on my google analytics home page?

Comment: No, you can just create a single new Analytics Property, then use the tracking code from that property in every customers search widget. You can customize it by changing the word 'used' to each individual customer ID number. Then in GA you'll see the events broken down by total number used across all of your customers, or just by a specific customer, or by a specific search term.